# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ProfID=200900001 AND ProfTime=8:00:00 AM'

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    Handles Button1.Click

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim x As New Integer
    Dim profID As New Integer
    Dim date1 As New Date
    date1 = #8:00:00 AM#
    profID = 200900001
    x = 0
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    cmd.Connection = cnn
    'SerialPort1.Open()
    'SerialPort1.Write("1")
    'Dim readThis As String = SerialPort1.ReadChar()
    'MsgBox(readThis)
    'If readThis = 1 Then
    'End If
    'SerialPort1.Close()
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE test " & _
                      "SET ProfLog='" & x & "'" & _
                      "WHERE ProfID=" & profID & "  AND ProfTime=" & date1
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("DONE!")

End Sub
```

with this code, it says that there is a

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ProfID=200900001  AND ProfTime=8:00:00 AM'.
```

What is the missing operator?

Comment: Consider a parameter query for this.  Those are often recommended to avoid SQL injection risks.  But they can also allow you to use date and string values without bothering about delimiters.

Comment: Please show the entire query, but you might need to add a space after the apostrophe:  `SET ProfLog='" & x & "' "`

Answer (score 2):

You need to repeat the `#` notation in the where clause so access knows the value is a date:

```
... & _
"WHERE ProfID = " & profID & " AND ProfTime = #" & date1 & "#"
```

(The reason being, as a contrived example, is `where x = 1/2/3` a date or *1-divided-by-2-divided-by-3* ..)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends upon the target.

For MS Access - "ProfTime = #" & date1 & "#"

For SQL Server - "ProfTime = '" & date1 & "'"